# How to use UTIs to make a new file type?

Tags: objective-c, file, uti

I have been working on making an application for editing game plugins for a game I made. I needed the files it saves to have a custom format for obvious reasons. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to give the file a custom icon.

I did some research last night into UTIs, mostly because they are mentioned wherever icons are talked about. I did what the Apple Documentation said, but it didn't work.

Here is my code so far:

```
[@"test" writeToFile:@"test.hsimg" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

That works perfectly. The only problem I have now is that there is no icon. Could someone please tell me how I need to setup the UTIs to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these questions:

[How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

[Creating my own file extension based on plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827558/creating-my-own-file-extension-based-on-plist)