# UIDocumentPickerViewController files disabled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I have a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` with the following code:

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker =
    [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes: @[@"public.text", @"public.sql"]
                                                               inMode: UIDocumentPickerModeOpen];

documentPicker.delegate = self;
documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
[self presentViewController: documentPicker
                   animated: YES
                 completion: nil];
```

This opens the picker and I can pick .txt files, but I cannot pick .sql files. The following screenshot shows what a .sql file looks like in the picker.

[image: UIDocumentPickerViewController files disabled]

I've added the following to my `info.plist` file which to my understanding may be needed (ignore the UTTypeReferenceURL, I'm just trying to get this to work.)

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.sql</string>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>SQL statement(s)</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>public.sql</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>public.sql</string>
        <key>UTTypeReferenceURL</key>
        <string>http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

What do I need to do to have `UIDocumentPickerViewController` allow picking .sql file types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out based on another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827558/creating-my-own-file-extension-based-on-plist). I added the following to my info.plist:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>SQL statements</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.hankinsoft.sqlpro.sql</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>sql</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

And modified my `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to be as follows:

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker =
    [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes: @[@"com.hankinsoft.sqlpro.sql"]
                                                           inMode: UIDocumentPickerModeOpen];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `public.database` in place of `public.sql`.

Comment: `public.database` does not resolve the issue either. I'm thinking that may be for sqlite database files rather than sql scripts.